# postgresql not returning rows when where clause is present

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one to which a sensor logs different events as they occur, and a reference table that holds a list of all possible events. the sensor table is currently empty.

```
SELECT
    events.eventtype,
    count(sensor.eventtype)
FROM
    events
    LEFT JOIN sensor ON sensor.eventtype = events.eventtype
GROUP BY
    events.eventtype
```

this query correctly returns a list of events and their occurrence(0 for everything)

```
SELECT
    events.eventtype,
    count(sensor.eventtype)
FROM
    events
    LEFT JOIN sensor ON sensor.eventtype = allevents.eventtype
WHERE
    eventdate = '2019-06-19'
GROUP BY
    events.eventtype
```

this query however returns nothing. what difference does the where clause make?

Comment: where clause is filtering the results and then further grouping is performed. so I think that after applying filter there isn't any data left to group. please check.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the filtering condition to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT e.eventtype, count(s.eventtype)
FROM events e LEFT JOIN
     sensor s
     ON s.eventtype = e.eventtype AND
        s.eventdate = '2019-06-19'
GROUP BY e.eventtype;
```

The `LEFT JOIN` returns a `NULL` value for non-matches.  With the condition in the `WHERE` clause, these are filtered out.

As a general rule, when using a `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on the *first* table go in the `WHERE` clause.  Conditions on the subsequent tables go in the `ON` clause(s).